# Google images reverse image search via image url

Tags: google-image-search

Last year Ive been able to integrate a link like this into my webapp

```
https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=image_url
```

However this stopped working a few months ago does anyone have an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

It still works if you append the parameter `&client=app` at the end. It takes you to the legacy reverse image search results instead of the new UI then.

Reference: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/167766/reverse-google-image-search-via-url-after-2022-switch-to-google-lens